# Adding scores to game using cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am creating a game in cocos2d-x and i am trying to add scores in my game. First i declared a  score variable and set the value to 0. in Bool function using do while loop increased the value by 1, and using printf I displayed the score but it is not working.Please help me with some code.

```
Int score;
socre=0
do
{
printf("%d",score);
}while(score>=0)
```

Comment: show some code, what you tried?

Comment: Post your code. Post why it is not working, show us an error or what it is doing.

Comment: I added the code what i tried please help.

Comment: You misspelled the variable name `score` while initializing it to zero.

Comment: No while giving correct spelling also it is giving error.

Comment: I want to know hoe to set position for the score in the scene

Comment: Hey m talking about second line of you code. you have written `socre` instead of `score`.

Comment: No its correct only in my code actually i want to know how to set the position for score in the scene.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Is it about your variable socre not updated or anything else. Just post your code what you want to reach.

Answer (score 3):

If you are wanting to display your score graphically on a Layer

1. make a `cocos2d::Label`, see the documentation.
2. set its value: `label->setString(std::to_string(score));`
3. `addChild(label, 1);` in your Layer code where it makes sense.
4. `label->setPosition(...)`

There are a number of Label types and constructors that you can use, look up what you might want to use: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0/db/de4/classcocos2d_1_1_label.html

Here is a simple example using one of the provided constructors:

```
cocos2d::LabelBMFont* label = cocos2d::LabelBMFont::create(std::to_string(score), "Marker Felt");
label->setAlignment(cocos2d::TextHAlignment::CENTER);

addChild(label, 0);

label->setPosition(...);
```

When you need to update the score, as it changes, use something like:

```
_label->setString(std::to_string(score));
```